# Missing scrollbars & strange white edges

Tags: unity, scrollbar

Ever since I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04, I have had issues with the "native" scroll bars. This problem is happening in programs such as Nautilus, Eclipse, System Settings etc.. In other words; programs that seems to use the native desktop "tools".

[image: White "bars" top and bottom, and no scrollbar]

When I scroll, it looks like an "inverted" graphical feedback. Reminds me of some bouncing effect in the top and bottom.

If possible to scroll sidewards, the white bars will also display on the sides. Sort of making a white/gray border.

I have tried reinstalling ubuntu-desktop, unity, compizconfig-settings-manager, light-themes.

Scrolling is working normally in Google Chrome, Firefox, Terminal and the Ubuntu Dash.

I uploaded a video showing it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJKrUOgbGa4 
The last part of it is quiet slow, seems like some recording bug...